# Eliminating null usage in a Scala stack implementation

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala and am making some Stack implementations as practice. I made this and there are some apparent issues.

```
class LinkedStack[T] extends Stack[T] {
  var current: Node = null
  var n: Int = 0

  private class Node(e: T, prev: Node) {
    val element: T = e
    var previous: Node = prev
  }

  override def pop(): T = {
    if (n == 0) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException
    }
    val popNode: Node = current
    current = current.previous
    popNode.previous = null
    n -= 1

    popNode.element
  }

  override def peek(): T = {
    if (n == 0) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException
    }

    current.element
  }

  override def push(element: T): Unit = {
    if (element == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException
    }
    val newNode: Node = new Node(element, current)
    current = newNode

    n += 1
  }

  override def size(): Int = {
    n
  }

  override def toString(): String = {
    val builder = new StringBuilder("Stack top [")
    var temp: Node = current

    if (n == 0) {
      builder.append("]")
      return builder.toString()
    }
    while (temp.previous != null) {
      builder.append(temp.element).append(", ")
      temp = temp.previous
    }

    builder.append(temp.element).append("]")

    builder.toString()
  }
}
```

The trait includes all of the elements except toString. My main problem is that I'm using null pretty liberally. I know this shouldn't be done at all in Scala, and the line

```
var current: Node = null
```

in the constructor generates a compile error. How should I implement a constructor to create an empty stack? What's the best substitution for null?

**Edit:**
You may have noticed that the Node class should be rewritten as

```
private class Node(val element: T, var previous: Node) {}
```

I realized this after reading Rex Kerr's answer. I forgot that I was programming in Scala when I first wrote that.

Comment: To avoid null, immutability must be favored (no `var`)

Comment: mutable.Stack is based on ListBuffer with source https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/Stack.scala  in which "val empty: Stack[Nothing] = new Stack(Nil)".   Immutable.Stack is based on List with source in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stack.scala and the issue is avoided essentially by using the Nil of the empty List as the empty Stack. Both are good references for Scala stack design.

Comment: @cchantep - The converse is more true.  If you have immutability, `null` is an even bigger pain to deal with.  You can avoid `null` easily enough mutably, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing *terribly* wrong with using `null` as part of the internals for your class as long as those `null`s never leak out and the logic is straightforward enough so you can be sure of that.

But if you want to not use `null` for practice, you have two choices.  One is to use a built-in alternative: instead of `Node` use `Option[Node]` and use `None` for `null`.  Given that your list is invariant, this is the easier way.

Second, you can replace `Node` with a hierarchy like so:

```
trait Node
class Elt(val element: T, val previous: Node) extends Node {}
object End extends Node
```

And then you use `End` wherever you use `null` now, and match on the `Node` any time you need to walk or do something, e.g.

```
def peek = current match {
  case End => throw new NoSuchElementException
  case Elt(e, _) => e
}
```

Of course this means each list has to create an extra object (`End`), and there are various other drawbacks, most of which can be gotten around to some extent.  But for an exercise in avoiding `null`, you can ignore those complications.

Comment: Agreed that nothing is terribly wrong by using `null` internally but still I would make the fact - that a var might be null - explicit by using an `Option` , independent of the whole structure being mutable or immutable (a very very tiny memory and time overhead but a huge advantage of avoiding mistakes and such).

Comment: @RexKerr The first option would make pushing the first element problematic since `node.previous` cannot point to a none instance. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @user3599828 - You make `node.previous` hold `Option[Node]`.

Answer (score 1):

**i'm also scala learning my stack implementation ,it;s simple i used scala mutable array buffer**

```
object Stack{
var stack=scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()

def isEmpty():Boolean={
  if(stack.length==0) true
  else false
}

def push(input:Int):Unit={
  stack+=input
}

def size():Int={
  stack.length
}

 def pop():Int={
   stack.remove(stack.length-1)
 }

def peek()={
   stack(stack.length-1)
 }

}
```

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` is mutable. There is no reason to make `stack` a `var` as well.